# Add drop down lists in partial view with dynamic content mvc3

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, partial-views

I spent a few days to find a solution for my problem but I totally could not.
What I am doing is creating a search page for database. I am not sure how detailed the search is so I am using ajax/partial views for adding search criteria (I mean trying as this is the part what not working). 
I am maybe making a stupid mistake I have no idea... 
It is working without the ajax/partial view but that does not really serve the purpose of my project(not detailed enough).
My code is the following:

### So that is my ajax what calls the partial view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jScript1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


@Ajax.ActionLink("Add search criteria",
              "AddSearch", new AjaxOptions
              {
                  UpdateTargetId = "search",
                  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
                  HttpMethod = "POST",
                  OnSuccess = "DBUpdate"
              })

<div id="search">

</div>


<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

### my partial view:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.search    


<div id="a">

 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Table, Model.Tables, "-- Select Table --")
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Type, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Select Type --")
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "-- Select Name --")
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.less)
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.equ)
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.more)

</div>
```

### and my js file:

```
function DBUpdate() {


$('#Table').change(function () {
    var selectedTable = $(this).val();
    if (selectedTable != null && selectedTable != '') {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Types")', { Table: selectedTable }, function (types) {
            var typesSelect = $('#Type');
            typesSelect.empty();
            $.each(types, function (index, types) {
                typesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: types.value,
                    text: types.text
                }));
            });
        });
    }
});


$('#Type').change(function () {
    var selectedType = $(this).val();
    var selectedTable = $('#Table').val();
    if (selectedType != null && selectedType != '') {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Names")', { Type: selectedType, Table: selectedTable }, function (names) {
            var namesSelect = $('#Name');
            namesSelect.empty();
            $.each(names, function (index, names) {
                namesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: names.value,
                    text: names.text
                }));
            });
        });
    }
});


}
```

Thanks in advance for all of your help guys 
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- You are trying to use server side helpers such as `@Url.Action("Types")` in a separate javascript file which obviously is impossible.
- You are using id selectors such as `$('#Table')` and `$('#Type')` but you could have multiple rows and thus multiple dropdown lists with the same id => those are bad selectors => you no longer know which element you are selecting.

So let's start remedying those problems.

First we start by modifying the partial:

```
@model search    
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Table, 
        Model.Tables, 
        "-- Select Table --", 
        new { 
            id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            @class = "tables", 
            data_url = Url.Action("Types") 
        }
    )

    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Type, 
        Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), 
        "-- Select Type --", 
        new { 
            id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            @class = "types",
            data_url = Url.Action("Names") 
        }
    )

    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Name, 
        Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), 
        "-- Select Name --", 
        new { 
            id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            @class = "names" 
        }
    )

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.less)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.equ)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.more)
</div>
```

Notice that I have applied class attributes to the dropdown lists so that I can more easily select them in my javascript. I have also associated an url to the first 2 dropdown lists so that we can cascade them to the corresponding controller actions later.

Talking about cascades let's write a jQuery plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cascade = function (options) {
        var defaults = { 
            additionalParameters: function() {
                return { };
            } 
        };
        var opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                var params = opts.additionalParameters() || {};
                params[opts.paramName] = selectedValue;
                $.getJSON($(this).data('url'), params, function (items) {
                    opts.childSelect.empty();
                    $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                        opts.childSelect.append(
                            $('<option/>')
                                .attr('value', item.value)
                                .text(item.text)
                        );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Armed with this plugin we can now go ahead and modify the main view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ActionLink(
        "Add search criteria",
        "AddSearch",
        null,
        new { id = "add" }
    )
    <div id="search"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

and all that's left is to subscribe to the click event of the anchor (notice that I have used a normal `Html.ActionLink` instead of an `Ajax.ActionLink`) and attach our plugin:

```
$(function () {
    $('#add').click(function () {
        $.post(this.href, function (result) {
            var $result = $(result);
            $('#search').append($result);
            var tablesSelect = $('.tables', $result);
            var typesSelect = $('.types', $result);

            tablesSelect.cascade({
                paramName: 'table',
                childSelect: $('.types', $result)
            });
            typesSelect.cascade({
                paramName: 'type',
                additionalParameters: function () {
                    return { table: tablesSelect.val() };
                },
                childSelect: $('.names', $result)
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

All this can happen in a separate javascript file. This obviously assumes that we have the 2 corresponding controller actions that will return the JSON values of the cascading dropdown lists.

The following are just mocks so that you can see what's the input/output. You will of course replace the dummy values with something more realistic:

```
public ActionResult Types(string table)
{
    var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new
    {
        value = x,
        text = "type " + x
    });
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult Names(string type, string table)
{
    var model = Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(x => new
    {
        value = x,
        text = "name " + x
    });
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it is working perfect I just need to find out how to retrieve their data and thats all. Thanks again!!! You made my day guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `change` functions in document.ready()

```
$.document.ready(function () {
    $('#Table').change(function () {
     .....

    $('#Type').change(function () {
     ....
});
```

If you don't then the change event might be bound to an element that doesn't exist on the page yet - meaning it will never be bound.

EDIT

Try adding this to the main view

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I tried, unfortunately still not working(no error messages, no nothing). I have the same javascript code without that wrapping on one of my page and it is working there. Thanks anyway

Comment: where are you calling in your partial view? and let me see your action handling the POST

Comment: I do not post yet anything this is just setting up the content of the drop down lists. and how I call my partial view is just that:
public PartialViewResult AddSearch(search search)
        {

            return PartialView("_search", search);
        }

Comment: Well, you'll have to better define 'not working' What errors are you getting? Set breakpoints to make sure functions are being hit.

Comment: Sorry, ok tried a few things. I say it's "not working" as I get no error messages unfortunately. What I tried I put alerts in the JS file as I cant really set up break points there. When I put alert in the $.document.ready it never executes there. Without that the alert executes even in the last line of the function.

Comment: Tried a break point in the controller at the Types function. it does not execute. Do you think there could be some problem with my references?

Comment: If you look in a javascript console when you load the page, you'll see any errors loading the scripts. In IE just hit F12, click on the console tab, and reload the page

Comment: I said it was working on the main page without the ajax method but the JS is not linked there the page includes it, I took off the code put it in a JS file and included it. In that case nothing happened. I am almost sure the problem is the referencing.

Comment: I call the ajax add search criteria I choose one of the drop down list and instead of updating it I got a warning event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future. I guess that is not what causing the problem.

Comment: I put back the code what u suggested at the beginning than I get that error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of undefined

Comment: That means that you are not loading jQuery

Comment: I put it JQuery in the main file and in the partial view as well the way like that: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> but getting the same error

Comment: I changed $.document.ready to $(document).ready it is executes now but still not changing my drop down lists. I do not know that function so i don't know if its 2 different things or that's the normal syntax.

Comment: no, i messed up the syntax. does the controller action get hit now?

Comment: yeah it does but still nothing happens, my alert pops-up

Comment: I can not read... Sorry getting tired. No the controller action still not hit but the JS function runs throw. Thats why I think there could be some problem with my referencing in the JS function